# Как проводить манипуляции с URL для многоязыкового сайта сильно не переделывая рабочий сайт?

Tags: php, multilanguage

Провожу реинжиниринг {чужого} кода многоязыкового сайта на "простом" php.
Текущая реализация многоязыковости основана на значении внутренней переменной `$language`, которую можно менять при запуском специальной функции `language.php` с GET-параметром, которой языковая переменная меняется, идет возврат на исходную страницу, читается код языка, языковый контент изменяется, все путем.
Но при этом никак не меняется URL страницы, что не очень хорошо для SEO.
Задача - сделать дополнительный функционал, приводящий URL от

```
www.sitename.com/[page_address[.php]]
```

к виду

```
www.sitename.com/lang_code/[page_address[.php]]
```

где
`lang_code` - код языка: en, ru, es и т.д.,
`[.]` - означает, что объект "." может существовать, а может и нет,
существенно не меняя внутреннего функционала, т.е. нужен какой-то "перехватчик", преобразующий адрес с кодом языка в "стандартный", но не меняющий целевого адреса вызова страницы/ функции.
И, естественно, обратно - ввод адреса с языковым кодом должен переключать язык = выводить материал на выбранном языке.
Но т.к. сайт написан не CMS с их хуками и фильтрами, то не очень понятно, как он должен работать.
Хотелось бы обойтись без или минимумом `Rewrite`'ов в `.htaccess`, но если так нельзя, в частности - для корневого файла `index.php` - просьба меня "вернуть на путь истинный".
Просьба подсказать направление поиска или примеры решения.

Comment: Используйте .htaccess :-)

Answer (score 0):

Можно из веб-сервера в PHP передавать переменную окружения "язык" и перезаписывать адрес URI.

На примере настройки nginx, и использования префикса для языковых версий.

Конфигурация Nginx:

```
location /en/ {
  # перезаписываем URI, удаляя префикс
  rewrite  ^/en/(.*) /$1 break;
  # выставляем переменную окружения, которую будем использовать в PHP
  fastcgi_param   LANGUAGE  en;
  # ... остальные параметры
}

# аналогично
location /ru/ {
  rewrite  ^/ru/(.*) /$1 break;
  fastcgi_param   LANGUAGE  ru;
  # ... остальные параметры
}
```

Таким образом, все адреса `/ru/` и `/en/` перезаписываются на `/`, который обслуживает уже другой веб-сервер (Apache или напрямую php-fpm).

В `index.php` добавляем получение переменной окружения и выставляем вашу переменную `$language`

```
<?php
$language = getenv('LANGUAGE');
echo sprintf('Привет из index.php, язык: %s', $language);
```

Проверяем работу:

[image: пример]

Чисто в Apache можно сделать аналогично.

Если вам не нравится такая куча правил, это можно переделать через `map`, будет интерес - напишу решение.